# Worksheet Change Event

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code which I effectively want to rename worksheets based on the Value of I16. However if the target address is blank/ Nothing I wish to exit the sub. (this part of the code is not working).

If anyone could advise how I could resolve this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("I16")
Dim WSname As String
WSname = Range("I16").Value

If KeyCells Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Sheet23.Name = "BISSB"
Sheet25.Name = "RMIB"
Sheet26.Name = "MORIB"
Worksheets(WSname).Name = "Stage 3 V1"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
If KeyCells Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

use

```
If IsEmpty(KeyCells) Then Exit Sub
```

The **ISEMPTY** function can be used to check for blank cells. If cell is blank it will return `TRUE` else `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
If KeyCells Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

With:

```
If Trim(WSname) = "" Then Exit Sub
```

**Explanation**: you already use `Set KeyCells = Range("I16")` in your code, so you set your `KeyCells` Range, therefore it will never be `Nothing`.
You want to check the value of `KeyCells` range, and you have your `WSname` String variable.

Comment: @SeanBailey I would be careful using `IsEmpty` function, be careful of the "hiding" spaces. That function won't consider a cell with space in it as `Empty`, the `Trim` option will get rid of all the spaces

Answer (score 0):

You are already declare and set KeyCells to "I16". This is why if condition doesnt work - because KeyCells already contains cell. Ask if WSname = "" or check other way if it contains value or no.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to use Change Event code is to tell the code when to be automatically triggered and perform some actions.

Right now, your code will be triggered and perform the actions defined in the code each time when any cell on the sheet gets changed.

**I assume, you want to trigger the Change Event Code and perform some predefined actions only when the cell I16 gets changed and then rename the sheets as per the code. Right?**

If so, you may try something like this...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("I16")
Dim WSname As String
WSname = Range("I16").Value

If Not Intersect(Target, KeyCells) Is Nothing Then
    If Target <> "" Then
        Sheet23.Name = "BISSB"
        Sheet25.Name = "RMIB"
        Sheet26.Name = "MORIB"
        Worksheets(WSname).Name = "Stage 3 V1"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```